# How to give diferent colors to diferent lines in matplotlib

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, graph, label

```
materias = ["MAT 1","MAT 2","MAT 3","FIS 1","FIS 2","FIS 3","QUI 1","QUI 2","GEO 1","GEO 2","PORT","RED","LIT","ART","ING","HIST 1","HIST 2","FIL","SOC","EDF","BIO 1","BIO 2","BIO 3"
]
for i in materias:
    
    note= str(i)
    file_name = 'images/' + str(i) +'.png'
    print(i,":")
    plt.plot(df["PROVAS"], df[i], label=note)
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig(file_name)
    plt.show()
```

i dont know how to merge all of these graphs and dont know either how to give them different colors (to better visualisation)
(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `c=(R, G, B)` to the `plot()` call, where `R`, `G`, and `B` are values between 0 and 1.

For example,

```
colors = [(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)]
plt.plot(df["PROVAS"], df[i], c=colors[2], label=note)
```

will make the line green.
For your example, you could keep track of an index and step through the list of colors as you advance through the list of materials.